# Replacing Text within TextArea using Regular Expression is creating new lines

Tags: regex, vbscript, hta

I'm creating an HTML Application that allows the user to free-type into a `textarea`, then enter a regular expression pattern into one `input` box and a replace string into a second `input` box. When the user presses a button, a VBScript sequence runs that takes the user input, creates a regular expression and replaces the pattern with the string. My problem is that when a user selects the end of a line, i.e. a pattern of `$`, the replace string is added to every line and *inbetween* every line as well.

For example, the following text:

```
Test
Test
Test
```

If fed a replace string of `@` would output as:

```
Test@
@
Test@
@
Test@
```

How can I prevent the "additional" lines from appearing in the output? What's causing them in the first place?

The application code is as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<hta:application
    id="regexpengine"
    applicationname="RegExpEngine"
    icon="S:\Technical Projects\TechProd VB Projects\SPF Creator\SPF Creator\tools.ico"
    singleinstance="yes"
    border="thick"
    borderstyle="complex"
    scroll="yes"
    maximizebutton="no"
    version="0.1" />
<title>Regular Expression Engine</title>
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<script language="VBScript">
    ' Set Global Variables

        'Core Objects
        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

        'Input/Event Variables
        strInput = "No User Input"
        strExp = Empty
        strReplace = Empty
        strOutput = Empty
        strUserFunction = Empty
        strInstruction = Empty
        strUserConfirmedAction = Empty
        strOriginalInput = Empty

        'Custom Objects
        objRecord = False
        objGUIOption = "Type"

    Sub Window_onLoad()
    'Load Previously Entered Data if Available

        'Check that RAWFiles.txt exists and load any contained text
        'If objFSO.FileExists("C:\Temp\RAWFiles.txt") Then
        ''  Set objFileSize = objFSO.GetFile("C:\Temp\RAWFiles.txt")
        ''  If objFileSize.size > 0 Then
        ''      Set objFile=objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Temp\RAWFiles.txt",1)
        ''      strFileList=objFile.ReadAll
        ''      document.all.FileList.value=strFileList
        ''      objFile.Close
        ''  End If
        'End If

        'Load Previous Folder Values if Available
        'If objFSO.FileExists("C:\Temp\FolderLocation.txt") Then
        ''  Set objFileSize = objFSO.GetFile("C:\Temp\FolderLocation.txt")
        ''  If objFileSize.size > 0 Then
        ''      Set objFile=objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Temp\FolderLocation.txt",1)
        ''      strInputfolder=objFile.ReadLine
        ''      strOutputfolder=objFile.ReadLine
        ''      document.all.inputFolder.value=strInputfolder
        ''      document.all.outputFolder.value=strOutputfolder
        ''      objFile.Close
        ''  End If
        'End If

        'Force Window Size & Position
        window.resizeTo 885,750
        window.moveTo (screen.width - 885)/2, (screen.height - 750)/2

        'Hide File Input Option Until Selected
        document.all.selectFolder.style.display = "none"
        document.all.fileContents.style.display = "none"
    End Sub

    Sub UpdateMessage(strMessage,objType)
    'Update Message Area for Errors & User Decisions
        If objType = 2 Then
            LogArea.innerHTML = "<span class='error'>Error: " & strMessage & "</span><br>"
        Else
            LogArea.innerHTML = "<span class='update'>Message: " & strMessage & "</span><br>"
        End If
    End Sub

    Sub RunExpression
    'Take User Input & Run Expression Against File

        'Set Regular Expression
        Set objRegExp = New RegExp
        If strUserFunction="Replace" Then
            'Pattern for Replace Function - finds the first matched instance and then terminates
            With objRegExp
                .Pattern = strExp
                .IgnoreCase = False
                .Global = False
            End With
        Elseif strUserFunction="ReplaceAll" OR strUserFunction="Find" Then
            'Pattern for ReplaceAll & Find Functions - finds every matched instance
            With objRegExp
                .Pattern = strExp
                .IgnoreCase = False
                .Global = True
                .Multiline = True
            End With
        End If

        'Reset Output String
        strOutput = Empty

        'Perform User Selected Function
        If strUserFunction = "Replace" OR strUserFunction = "ReplaceAll" Then
            'Perform Replace - if the user input errors then capture the reason and end sequence

            On Error Resume Next
                'Replace on strReplace ensures that users can add in newlines using a standard \n
                strOutput = objRegExp.Replace(strInput,Replace(strReplace,"\n",vbNewLine))
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                Msgbox "Regular Expression Not Recognised",16,"Incorrect Syntax"
                Err.Clear
                UpdateMessage "Regular Expression Not Recognised - Incorrect Syntax - Instruction Failed",2
                strInstruction = Empty
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Elseif strUserFunction = "Find" Then
            Set objFind = objRegExp.Execute(strInput)
            strOutput = "Total Matches: " & objFind.Count & vbCRLF
            For Each Match in objFind
                strOutput = strOutput & "Matched: " & Match.Value & vbCRLF
            Next
            'Prevent Find Instructions from Being Committed
            strInstruction = Empty
        Else
            UpdateMessage "Run Attempted Without User Input - Run Terminated",2
            strInstruction = Empty
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'Write the Output to the Application Window - if the string has been replaced completely with a null value, output {EMPTY}
        If strOutput = "" Then
            expOutput.innerHTML = "{EMPTY}"
        Else
            document.getElementById("expOutput").appendChild(document.createTextNode(strOutput))
        End If

        'Inform User & Update if Recording
        If objRecord = True Then
            UpdateInput
            UpdateMessage "Performed Instruction Succesfully - Input Updated",1
            expOutput.innerHTML = "{RECORDING}"
        Else
            UpdateMessage "Performed Instruction Successfully",1
        End If
    End Sub

    Sub GetUserInput(strFunction)
    'Pull In User Input from Interface

        'Reset Error Message
        expOutput.innerHTML = ""

        'Determine Which Function was Requested (which button was pressed)
        strUserFunction = strFunction

        'Set User Input Data
        If userInputMethod.selectInputMethod(0).checked Then
            If Not userInput.Value = "" Then
                strInput = userInput.Value
            Else
                UpdateMessage "Free Typed Input is Selected but Textarea is Blank",2
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Elseif userInputMethod.selectInputMethod(1).checked Then
            If Not fileContents.Value = "" Then
                strInput = fileContents.Value
            Else
                UpdateMessage "Selected File is Blank",2
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'Set Expression
        If Not inputExp.Value = "" Then
            strExp = inputExp.Value
        Else
            UpdateMessage "No Expression Entered",2
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'Set Replace
        If Not replaceExp.Value = "" Then
            strReplace = replaceExp.Value
        Else
            strReplace = ""
        End If

        'Save Instruction
        If objRecord = True Then
            If Not strInstruction = Empty Then
                strInstruction = strInstruction & vbCRLF & strUserFunction & "," & strExp & "," & strReplace
            Else
                strInstruction = strUserFunction & "," & strExp & "," & strReplace
            End If
        Else
            strInstruction = strUserFunction & "," & strExp & "," & strReplace
        End If

        RunExpression
    End Sub

    Sub ChooseTextArea
    'Display User Input Textarea

        'Update GUI
        document.all.userInput.style.display="block"
        document.all.selectFolder.style.display="none"
        document.all.fileContents.style.display = "none"

        'Set Choice
        objGUIOption = "Type"
    End Sub

    Sub ChooseFile
    'Display File Input

        'Update GUI
        document.all.userInput.style.display="none"
        document.all.selectFolder.style.display="inline"
        If Not fileContents.Value = "" Then
            document.all.fileContents.style.display = "block"
        End If

        'Set Choice
        objGUIOption = "File"
    End Sub

    Sub UploadSelectedFile
    'Check User Selected File Exists & Load Contained Text

        'Reset Error Message
        expOutput.innerHTML = ""

        'Get User Input & Sanitise
        objFilePath = fileInput.Value
        objFilePath = Replace(objFilePath,chr(34),"")

        'Extract Data from File
        If objFSO.FileExists(objFilePath) Then
            Set objFileSize = objFSO.GetFile(objFilePath)
            If objFileSize.size > 0 Then
                Set objFile=objFSO.OpenTextFile(objFilePath,1)
                strFileContents=objFile.ReadAll
                document.all.fileContents.value=strFileContents
                objFile.Close
            Else
                UpdateMessage "Selected Filed is Blank",2
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Else
            UpdateMessage "Input File Does Not Exist",2
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'Make Textarea Visible
        document.all.fileContents.style.display = "block"
    End Sub

    Sub CommitInstruction
    'Save Current Instruction to Recipe

        'Check that Instruction Exists
        If strInstruction = Empty Then
            UpdateMessage "Instruction is Blank or Does Not Exist",2
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'Check whether a Recipe Exists
        If objFSO.FileExists("C:\Temp\Temp_Recipe.txt") Then
            Set objRecipe = objFSO.GetFile("C:\Temp\Temp_Recipe.txt")

            'Check the Recipe Contains Instructions
            If objRecipe.size > 0 And strUserConfirmedAction = "" Then

                'Check How User Wants to Interact with Present Recipe - Overwrite or Amend?
                userConfirm = Msgbox("A partial Recipe already exists. Should it be deleted?",35,"How to Proceed?")

                'User Decision: Overwrite (Yes - 6) or Amend (No - 7)
                If userConfirm = 6 Then
                    strUserConfirmedAction = "Overwrite"
                Elseif userConfirm = 7 Then

                    'Request Further User Input
                    userConfirm = Msgbox("Amend the partial Recipe with new Instructions?",33,"How to Proceed?")
                    If userConfirm = 1 Then
                        strUserConfirmedAction = "Amend"
                    Elseif userConfirm = 2 Then
                        'Cancel Operation & Open Temp Folder
                        Msgbox "Delete Current Recipe & Try Again",64,"Operation Cancelled"
                        userConfirm = Empty
                        UpdateMessage "Commit Cancelled by User",2
                        Set objShell = CreateObject("shell.application")
                        objShell.Open("C:\Temp")
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                Elseif userConfirm = 2 Then
                    UpdateMessage "Commit Cancelled by User",2
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Elseif strUserConfirmedAction = "" Then
                'If Recipe is Blank, Assume Amending
                strUserConfirmedAction = "Amend"
            End If
        Else
            'Set Field so that Recipe will be Created
            strUserConfirmedAction = "Amend"
        End If

        'Write Instruction to Recipe
        If strUserConfirmedAction = "Overwrite" Then
            'Overwrite Current Recipe & Set to Amend for Further Commits
            Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Temp\Temp_Recipe.txt",2,1)
            objFile.WriteLine strInstruction
            objFile.Close
            strUserConfirmedAction = "Amend"
        Elseif strUserConfirmedAction = "Amend" Then
            'Append Current Instruction to Recipe
            Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Temp\Temp_Recipe.txt",8,1)
            objFile.WriteLine strInstruction
            objFile.Close
        End If

        'Clear Instruction
        strInstruction = Empty

        'Update Input
        UpdateInput
        UpdateMessage "Instruction Saved and Input Updated",1
    End Sub

    Sub DeleteRecipe
    'User Requests to Delete Current Recipe

        'Ensure User Confirmation is Empty
        strUserDelete = Empty

        'Check that a Recipe Exists
        If objFSO.FileExists("C:\Temp\Temp_Recipe.txt") Then
            'Request User Confirmation
            strUserDelete = Msgbox("Delete Unsaved Recipe Permanently?",17,"Delete File Permanently")
        Else
            UpdateMessage "No Recipe Found - Cannot Delete",2
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'Delete Recipe
        If strUserDelete = 1 Then
            objFSO.DeleteFile("C:\Temp\Temp_Recipe.txt")
            UpdateMessage "Partial Recipe Deleted",1
        Else
            UpdateMessage "User Cancelled Delete Operation",2
        End If
    End Sub

    Sub PreviewRecipe
    'Preview Current Recipe

        'Ensure Values are Empty
        strRecipePreview = Empty

        'Check that a Recipe Exists
        If Not objFSO.FileExists("C:\Temp\Temp_Recipe.txt") Then
            UpdateMessage "Recipe Cannot Be Found",2
            Exit Sub
        Else
            Set objRecipe = objFSO.GetFile("C:\Temp\Temp_Recipe.txt")
            If Not objRecipe.size > 0 Then
                strRecipePreview = "{EMPTY}"
                UpdateMessage "Recipe is Currently Blank",1
            End If
        End If

        'Retrieve & Display Recipe
        Set objRecipe = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Temp\Temp_Recipe.txt",1)
        If strRecipePreview = Empty Then
            strRecipePreview = objRecipe.ReadAll
        End If
        Msgbox strRecipePreview,64,"Recipe Preview:"
    End Sub

    Sub RecordInstructions
    'Continuously Commit Instructions as Each if Run by User

        'Reset Button State & User Input
        strButtonPressed = False
        strUserCommit = Empty

        'Start Recording
        If objRecord = False And strButtonPressed = False Then
            If Not strInstruction = Empty Then
            'Request User Input - Delete or Keep Current Instruction?
                strUserCommit = Msgbox("Commit Current Instruction?",35,"Instruction Already Exists")
                If strUserCommit = 6 Then
                    CommitInstruction
                    'If Commit is Cancelled by User then Don't Continue
                    If Not strInstruction = Empty Then
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                Elseif strUserCommit = 7 Then
                    strInstruction = Empty
                Elseif strUserCommit = 2 Then
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End If
            objRecord = True
            strButtonPressed = True
            UpdateMessage "Recording Instructions Initiated",1
            runRecord.innerHTML = "Stop (<span class='quickKey'>d</span>)"
        End If

        'Stop Recording
        If objRecord = True And strButtonPressed = False Then
            If Not strInstruction = Empty Then
            'Request User Input - Delete or Commit Recording?
                strUserCommit = Msgbox("Commit Recorded Instructions?",35,"Recording Ended")
                If strUserCommit = 6 Then
                    CommitInstruction
                    'If Commit is Cancelled by User then Don't Continue
                    If Not strInstruction = Empty Then
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                Elseif strUserCommit = 7 Then
                    strInstruction = Empty
                Elseif strUserCommit = 2 Then
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End If
            objRecord = False
            strButtonPressed = True
            UpdateMessage "Recording Instructions Terminated",1
            runRecord.innerHTML = "Recor<span class='quickKey'>d</span>"
        End If
    End Sub

    Sub UpdateInput
    'Refresh the Input After a Commit to Allow Continual Editing

        'Save Original Text on First Commit
        If strOriginalInput = Empty Then
            strOriginalInput = strInput
        End If

        'Update Input
        strInput = strOutput

        'Update GUI
        If objGUIOption = "Type" Then
            userInput.innerHTML = strInput
        Else
            fileContents.innerHTML = strInput
        End If
        expOutput.innerHTML = ""
    End Sub

    Sub Test
        Msgbox(strOutput)
    End Sub
</script>
<style>
    body {
        margin: 0 20px;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: "Segoe UI", Geneva, sans-serif;
        background: #f3f3f3;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 15pt;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        color: #273754;
    }
    pre {
        line-height: 8px;
        font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace, sans-serif;
        background: #ffffff;
        height: 150px;
        overflow: auto;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    button {
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: 100;
        color: #fff;
        background: #777d84;
        border: 0;
    }
    button.select {
        padding: 5px 10px;
        font-size: 12px;
        margin: 0 1px;
    }
    button:hover {
        background: #646a70;
    }
    input[type=text] {
        height: 20px;
        width: 72%;
    }
    textarea {
        overflow: auto;
    }
    .error {
        color: #e22b2b;
    }
    .folderInput {
        width: 85%;
        margin: auto;
    }
    .folderSelect {
        margin:0 20px 0 0;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        width: 100px;
    }
    .buttonContainer {
        margin: auto;
        text-align: center;
    }
    input[type=button].featureButton {
        width: 100px;
        font-size: 12px;
        padding: 5px 10px;
    }
    span.quickKey {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    #logArea {
        height: 8px;
    }
    #retrieveRAW {
        margin-top: 20px;
        font-weight: bold;
        background: #4a8e0b;
    }
    .right {
        float: right;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div>
        <H1>Test Regular Expression</H1>
        <p>
            <form id="userInputMethod">
                <span class="option">Free Type Input:</span>
                <input name="selectInputMethod" type="radio" onClick="ChooseTextArea" checked>
                <span class="option">Select File Input:</span>
                <input name="selectInputMethod" type="radio" onClick="ChooseFile">
            </form>
            <textarea name="userInput" rows=10 cols=100></textarea>
            <span id="selectFolder"><input type="text" id="fileInput" size=100><button id="runFolder" onClick="UploadSelectedFile">Submit</button></span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <textarea name="fileContents" rows=10 cols=100></textarea>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>
            Regular Expression to Test:<br>
            <input type="text" id="inputExp" size=100>
        </p>
        <p>
            Replace With:<br>
            <input type="text" id="replaceExp" size=100>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button id="runReplace" onClick="GetUserInput('Replace')" accessKey="r"><span class="quickKey">R</span>eplace</button>
        <button id="runReplaceAll" onClick="GetUserInput('ReplaceAll')" accessKey="a">Replace <span class="quickKey">A</span>ll</button>
        <button id="runFind" onClick="GetUserInput('Find')" accessKey="f"><span class="quickKey">F</span>ind</button>
        <span class="right">
            <button id="runCommit" onClick="CommitInstruction" accessKey="c"><span class="quickKey">C</span>ommit</button>
            <button id="runRecord" onClick="RecordInstructions" accessKey="d">Recor<span class="quickKey">d</span></button>
            <button id="runPreview" onClick="PreviewRecipe" accessKey="v">Pre<span class="quickKey">v</span>iew</button>
            <button id="runDelete" onClick="DeleteRecipe">Delete</button>
            <button id="runTest" onClick="Test" accessKey="t"><span class="quickKey">T</span>est</button>
            <button id="runCook" onClick="Test" accessKey="k">Coo<span class="quickKey">k</span></button>
        </span><br><br>
    </div>
    <div>
        <pre id="logArea">Ready to Begin...</pre>
    </div>
    <div>
        <pre id="expOutput"></pre>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*Pattern* Property documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f97kw5ka.aspx) is too brief about `$` pattern character:

> `$` Matches the end of input.

For more detailed specification, read [Regular Expression Programming (Scripting)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee236360(v=vs.85).aspx) article (scroll down to the *Flags* paragraph). In brief:

> ### Flags
>
> In the JScript regular expression `/abc/gim`, the `g` specifies the
>   *global* flag, the `i` specifies the *ignore case* flag, and the `m` specifies the *multiline* flag.
>
> In VBScript, you can specify these flags by setting the equivalent
>   properties to `True`.
>
> …
>
> *Multiline*
>
> - `^` matches positions following a `\n` or `\r`, and
> - `$` matches positions before `\n` or `\r`.

**Actually**, `$` matches positions before `\n` (<kbd>LF</kbd>) **and** before `\r` (<kbd>CR</kbd>).

*The case explanation*:

- **if** the input field is **Test<kbd>CR</kbd><kbd>LF</kbd>Test<kbd>CR</kbd><kbd>LF</kbd>Test**

  - and regex pattern is **`$`**
  - and *Replace* field is **`@`**
- **then** `Replace All` action results to **Test@<kbd>CR</kbd>@<kbd>LF</kbd>Test@<kbd>CR</kbd>@<kbd>LF</kbd>Test@**

**Solution** (not generally true):

- use `\b$` pattern (it would not match end of an empty line or end of a line with any trailing white space including space, tab etc.)
- use `\r\n` pattern **and** trailing `\n` in the *Replace with* field (it would not match last line not ending with `\r\n` i.e. <kbd>CR</kbd><kbd>LF</kbd>).

For debugging purposes, I have improved the HTA code from line #147 using the following code stub:

```
    Else
        UpdateMessage "Performed Instruction Successfully",1
        If strUserFunction <> "Find" Then
          MsgBox  HexScan(strInput  , "strInput"  ) _
                & HexScan(strReplace, "strReplace") _
                & HexScan(strOutput , "strOutput" ), vbOKOnly, "hexadecimals" 
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Function HexScan( Byval strStr, strHead)
    HexScan = strHead & Space(1) & CStr( Len(strStr)) & vbNewLine & "hex "
    For ii = 1 To Len(strStr)
      HexScan = HexScan & Right( "0" & Hex(Asc(Mid(strStr,ii,1))),2) & " "
    Next
    HexScan = HexScan & vbNewLine
End Function

Sub GetUserInput(strFunction)
'Pull In User Input from Interface
```